# DEV 501 CERTIFICATION ISSUE

Tags: certification

I had an exam scheduled at 10.30 AM today but due to some biometric issues i was unable to launch my exam and then after 20 mins it was saying your exam has passed. I raised so many cases with sfdc but couldn't receive any response from their end till now.
Please someone know the direct SF contact please share it with me asap.Its an urgent urgent help required.

Comment: glad that you are passed , if failed there many lot issues ? but how can it will be possible?  and contact https://help.salesforce.com/HTUnauthContactSupport

Comment: I mean to say exam time has passed. Due to biometric issue i was unable to launch and after that my exam time passed.

Comment: oh:-)???? i m sorry i thought result came automatically as passed...:-)

Comment: I had technical issues with one of my exams and sf customer support was able to get me a new test time. I don't have any special contact information though. I just submitted a case through the regular channels.

Comment: ok...i have also raised cases with the salesforce but havent received any response from their end and its been almost 10 hrs when i did...Martin did u pay one more time for the reschedule exam or they adjusted your previous amount for the new exam..??

Comment: I remember it taking about a day before they responded to my case. Once they got someone on it, the communication was good and they were able to get me set up with a new test time pretty quick. In my situation, I didn't have to pay anything extra, but I can't guarantee that is always the case.

Comment: Yea, it took me a few days to hear back about my case in a situation like this. They gave me a coupon code worth the full value of my test. It was fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can find their contact details [here.](http://www.kryteriononline.com/Support) At the bottom left you can talk to someone online. When doing my exam I found their online team really useful so would recommend that! Additionally, contact numbers are below too.

**Edit:**

I should clarify that Kryterion deal with WebAssessor that deals with Salesforce qualifications.

Good luck!